# Find keys that exist in one map but not in the other

Tags: elixir

I have 2 maps. What's the way to find out what keys exist in one `Map`, but they don't exist in the other one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`Map.keys/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#keys/1) with [`--`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#--/2) is the simplest way to do this:

```rb
# Suppose your two maps are:
map_a = %{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4}
map_b = %{c: 3, d: 4, e: 5, f: 6}


# Get keys present in map_a but not in map_b
a_b_diff = Map.keys(map_a) -- Map.keys(map_b)        # => [:a, :b]


# Get keys present in map_b but not in map_a
b_a_diff = Map.keys(map_b) -- Map.keys(map_a)        # => [:e, :f]
```

Comment: ok. and if I merely have a list of keys and a map and I want to check which keys don't exist in a map, how can I do that?

Comment: You can use [`Map.has_key?`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#has_key?/2) or something like: `keys -- Map.keys(map)`

Comment: what's the `--`?

Answer (score 3):

`--` is extremely inefficient for large lists. Since you already have a Map, you can look up the existence of any key in `O(log n)` time using `Map.has_key?/2`. A simple `for` with a filter can be used to get the result you want:

```
iex(1)> map1 = %{a: 1, b: 2, d: 3, f: 4}
%{a: 1, b: 2, d: 3, f: 4}
iex(2)> map2 = %{b: 5, c: 6, f: 7, g: 8}
%{b: 5, c: 6, f: 7, g: 8}
iex(3)> for {k, _} <- map1, !Map.has_key?(map2, k), do: k
[:a, :d]
```

A quick benchmark with large map shows the huge performance difference vs `Kernel.--/2`:

```
map1 = for x <- Enum.take_random(1..10000, 5000), into: %{}, do: {x, x}
map2 = for x <- Enum.take_random(1..10000, 5000), into: %{}, do: {x, x}

{time, result1} = :timer.tc(fn ->
  Map.keys(map1) -- Map.keys(map2)
end)
IO.puts "--: #{time}µs"

{time, result2} = :timer.tc(fn ->
  for {k, _} <- map1, !Map.has_key?(map2, k), do: k
end)
IO.puts "for: #{time}µs"

IO.inspect result1 == result2
```

Output:

```
--: 113367µs
for: 739µs
true
```

If your maps are small though, `--` is definitely slightly shorter and more readable than this and should be good enough.